# Cubic surfaces not containing lines.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I can't understand the following assertion, from *Shafarevic,Basic Algebraic Geometry,Vol 1,pag 80*.

It is easy to construct a cubic surface $X\subset\mathbb{A}^3$ not containing lines. For example, if $X$ is given by

$$T_1T_2T_3=1$$
then $X$ does not have a single line contained in $\mathbb{A}^3$. Indeed, if we write the equation of an affine line in the form $T_i=a_it+b_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and substitute in the equation above, we get a contradiction.

I did the substituion and I got the following relation

$$a_1a_2a_3t^3+(a_1a_2b_3+a_1b_2a_3+b_1a_2a_3)t^2+(a_1b_2b_3+b_1a_2b_3+b_1b_2a_3)t+b_1b_2b_3=1$$

Well, where is the contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the whole line, so it has to be true for all $t$.  So the left-hand side has to have the coefficients of $t^3$, $t^2$ and $t$ equal to 0, and the constant term equal to 1.

Since $a_1a_2a_3=0$, you need $a_1=0$ say.  Can you take it from there?